# Is there move semantics in Go

Tags: go, move-semantics

I guess an object returned from a function (like `New()` style constructors) is **moved** outside, which is done by compiler implicitly.

There are already `pointers` and implicit `reference` semantics (`slice`, `map`, `chan`, and [closure capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873321/go-closure-captured-variable-and-shared-data)) in Go, except `copy`, and `move` semantics is another way to operate on some specific memory, which exists in `C++` and `Rust` for memory efficiency.

Comment: @blackgreen Yes, I did search before I post my question, why can't I find it?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ , I did Google "go move semantics" (first result) and SO search "[go] move semantics" (first result). SO search is usually not very good, but adding the tags with `[ ]` may help

Comment: @blackgreen I find in my original post I misspell the word "semantic" instead of "semantics" in title. After I correct it now I can find these 2 post in SO when search for "Move Semantics in Go", thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there move semantic in Go [?]

No.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Go official document](https://golang.org/doc/), there is no explicit syntax for move operation. If there is any, that would be defined by the compiler implementation, not language specification.